# Arcpy Insert.da.Cursor - Issues writing polygon geometry

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geometry, cursor

Currently building a tool that automates the creation of some polygons that we need done quarterly.  Below is just a set script I am using that is giving me a similar issue when I try to run the script.  The current output only gives me a polygon with 4 vertices and it is not making a point for each coordinate I have listed.  This full script is much larger and complex this is just the one part I am stuck on for some reason.  This sample is one of my variations I have tried.

## Code

```
import arcpy

workspace = r"....\Workspace\WritingGeometries"
coordinateSystem = 4326
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = coordinateSystem

fcPointTest = "TestPolygon"
fcPointPath = dsPath + "\\" + fcPointTest
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(dsPath, fcPointTest, "POLYGON")

testCord3 = [arcpy.Point(-95.542806, 30.720361),
             arcpy.Point(-95.479499, 30.805696),
             arcpy.Point(-95.499301, 30.814402),
             arcpy.Point(-95.509831, 30.817513),
             arcpy.Point(-95.516297, 30.818963),
             arcpy.Point(-95.520657, 30.819754),
             arcpy.Point(-95.523791, 30.820232),
             arcpy.Point(-95.526151, 30.820543),
             arcpy.Point(-95.527991, 30.820756),
             arcpy.Point(-95.529465, 30.820909),
             arcpy.Point(-95.530674, 30.821021),
             arcpy.Point(-95.531681, 30.821107),
             arcpy.Point(-95.532535, 30.821174),
             arcpy.Point(-95.533267, 30.821227),
             arcpy.Point(-95.533901, 30.821270),
             arcpy.Point(-95.534457, 30.821305),
             arcpy.Point(-95.542806, 30.821560),
             arcpy.Point(-95.534457, 30.821305),
             arcpy.Point(-95.533901, 30.821270),
             arcpy.Point(-95.533267, 30.821227),
             arcpy.Point(-95.532535, 30.821174),
             arcpy.Point(-95.531681, 30.821107),
             arcpy.Point(-95.530674, 30.821021),
             arcpy.Point(-95.529465, 30.820909),
             arcpy.Point(-95.527991, 30.820756),
             arcpy.Point(-95.526151, 30.820543),
             arcpy.Point(-95.523791, 30.820232),
             arcpy.Point(-95.520657, 30.819754),
             arcpy.Point(-95.516297, 30.818963),
             arcpy.Point(-95.509831, 30.817513),
             arcpy.Point(-95.499301, 30.814402),
             arcpy.Point(-95.606112, 30.805696)]

#Begin Processing
array = arcpy.Array(testCord3)
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fcPointPath, ["SHAPE@"])
cursor.insertRow([polygon])

del cursor
```

## Below is a screenshot of what my output is.

[image]

## Solution

Once Paul helped me out and noticed an error in my coordinates I was able to get the script to run through with 0 issues.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why the other vertices are not showing up. Maybe use copy features tool and see what happens

Comment: This is a coordinate reference issue.  You should always extract the coordinate reference from the source feature class and apply it at geometry construction, because the default constructor assumes a projected coordinate system and millimeter (0.001) precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point locations are what's causing the issue. If you add them in as points, you'll see that 14 of the points are coincident, meaning you are trying to create a polygon part that has 0 area (a line essentially). If you remove all those points, you'll see the result is actually the same.

Don't forget to close your polygons and set the spatial_reference when constructing the `Polygon` object:

```py
testCord3.append(testCord3[0])
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array, arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem)
```

Take a look at `polygon.getPart(0)` and `array` in your IDE to see what's happening. Nothing wrong with the cursor at all.

Comment: Thank you Paul and everyone else who took time to reply to my post.  I am happy to say the problem is now resolved.  Paul you made the comment that my points are coincident and it never even occurred to me that I should QC that.  Come to find out earlier in the script my math had an addition sign where it should have had a subtraction sign to calculate the points on the other side of the sector.  Once I fixed that and got my coordinates correct the polygon mapped out as it should.  Also great point on making sure I close my polygons, everything is working like a champ.  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: @HiMyNameIzMatt, huzzah! Welcome to GIS.SE :)

Comment: @HiMyNameIzMatt If Paul's answer has solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I converted your coordinates into a `POLYGON` in Well-Known Text and got an error (*polygon does not close properly*), so I added the first point to the end of the point list, and generated this shape:
[image]

Then I created a `LINESTRING` in Well-Known Text and from there into a shapefile and got this:

[image]

Then I shifted to `POINT` and got this (draped over the line, with vertex order labeled):

[image]

So it appears that you have a zero-area extension between the third and final vertices, which ArcGIS has "helpfully" removed.

Guidelines for constructing geometry in ArcPy:

- Always extract the `SpatialReference` from a feature class (this is **not** the same as a *coordinate system*) before constructing geometries:

  `sr = arcpy.Describe(tabPath).spatialReference`

  You can use the SpatialReference used to *create* the feature class, but then it's wise to specify the origin and units which correspond to your data (in this case, with 6 digits precision, one millionth of a degree)

  `sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)`

  `sr.setFalseOriginAndUnits(-400.0,-400.0,1000000.0)`

  but be forewarned that in certain cases, the created feature class may have different parameters than what was requested, so extracting from a `Describe` is safer.
- Always apply the coordinate reference in the geometry constructor

  `polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array,sr)`
- Always include the closing point in polygons (yes, ArcGIS, will do it for you, but this may mask issues)

  ```
       arcpy.Point(-95.499301, 30.814402),
       arcpy.Point(-95.606112, 30.805696),
       arcpy.Point(-95.542806, 30.720361)]
  ```
- If something goes wrong, try plotting your coordinates, first as lines, then as points, if necessary, to review correctness.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, a bad list of coordinates ended up being the main contributor for the problem.  I was neglectful and didn't QC the list I was testing from the beginning and once I revised the list my issue was resolved.  Thanks again!